# Определение времени глагола

Tags: глаголы

Добрый день. Объясните, пожалуйста: Глаголы с приставкой ПО- используются в следующих ситуациях:
1. Когда мы хотим сказать о желании, намерении или возможности идти или ехать, мы используем конструкцию хоте́ть, мочь + пойти / поехать: "Я хочу́ пойти́ в кино́".
2. Приставка ПО- обозначает начало движения, поэтому глаголы пойти / поехать используются для обозначения НАЧАЛА движения в каком-либо направлении: "Она пошла в кино́."  "Он пое́хал в Ки́ев".
3. Если мы описываем последовательность передвижений, то мы тоже используем глаголы с приставкой ПО-, чтобы обозначить начало каждого движения: "Вчера́ я снача́ла пошел в магази́н, пото́м пошел в кино́".
 В первом и третьем пунктах все понятно. Но во втором: "Пойти - начать идти, двигаться". Сейчас, в данный момент. Говорят, например: "Я ПОШЕЛ/ПОЕХАЛ в магазин" (именно сейчас). Как понять, что глаголы ПОЙТИ/ПОЕХАТЬ - совершенного вида, которые могут встречаться только в прошедшем или будущем времени, во втором случае используются в настоящем времени?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А и никак они не используются в настоящем времени. В настоящем времени будет "Я иду в магазин". Я пошел в магазин - вы себя считаете уже ушедшим из квартиры, в прошедшем времени.